# how to delete modules which are alredy uninstall?

Tags: 7

I have set of modules in my system but those modules are not properly un installed 
from the file system i have removed all modules but name aad path of the module still remains
in system table

Any one please suggest me how to clear this garbage ?

Comment: I have already used drush rr but its not working

Answer (score 2):

Unless you disable and uninstall the custom modules you should not remove that custom module . This can cause performance and other issues. Get back those modules from backup. Then disable and uninstall them. Then you can remove the module.

There is even a module in Drupal 7 which will tell you deleted but not disabled modules which I'm not able to remember.

Answer (score 0):

If the modules really haven't uninstalled properly then you'll need to manually go though the install files for each, and make sure you carry out all the actions on their behalf.

Far more likely, though, is that they *have* uninstalled properly but because you've left the files there, Drupal still picks them up in the system table, as they're fair game to be re-installed (Drupal module discovery is file based, so as long as the files are there, Drupal will find them).

So just delete the relevant module folders from your Drupal install, ensuring you take a backup of both files and database before hand in case there's a problem. If that happens, you'll need to cleanup manually, steps for which will completely depend on the modules you have installed/your config/etc.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick reply ,but I have already removed all modules from the system ,actually when I try to run codder module that time in listing i am seeing all those crap module because system tables have entry for those tables

Comment: If you've made sure those modules have been removed cleanly (see first paragraph in the answer) then you can safely delete the errant rows from the system table. Take a backup up first though, as always